# linphone SIP GSM codec

Tags: ios, codec, gsm, linphone

I use linphone open source to develop VOIP app on iOS platform. I use wireshark to capture packet while calling. I want app use GSM codec so I config just using GSM. The problem is when capturing via wireshark, on Message Body/Media Attribute/MIME type field, the value is telephone-event, so I wonder this value is equivalent to GSM or not.

Am I right, I search much on the Internet, but not see any evident proving that.

Comment: I'm having this exact problem.  Did you ever figure it out?